# Remove /component/virtuemart/ from manufacturer module on frontpage

Tags: joomla-2.5, virtuemart

I'm currently having a strange issue on a website.

When on the frontpage from the site the module for displaying the manufacturers show the following URL:

```
http://www.example.com/components/virtuemart/manufacturer/[name-of-manufacturer]
```

But when I click on a virtuemart productview or on the manufacturer page, the same module displays the right URL:

```
http://www.example.com/webshop/manufacturer/[name-of-manufacturer]
```

I'm quite confused about this issue.

I even assigned the VM frontpage to a hidden menu item

Comment: Can you give me any feedback on my answer?

Answer (score 1):

Add manufacturers list view to hidden menu. This should be used if there is no specific menu item for current manufacturer.

Tested this on Joomla! 3.4, adding VM Front Page to hidden menu creates links correctly on every page, like `webshop/manufacturer/`. Maybe you could consider migrating to Joomla! 3.x?

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer, unfortunately I'm not able to upgrade easily. So on short term this is not really an option.

Comment: Ok. Did adding manufactures list view to hidden menu helped?

Comment: I will check that one tomorrow